# MySQL and SQLAlchemy integer diversion in WHERE clause

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a table that contains a column called `region_code` with `Integer` as its datatype. In my Python program I have this line:

```
region = session.query(Region).filter(Region.region_code/100 == region_prefix).one()
```

The important part here is the chosen **filter** method

```
Region.region_code/100 == region_prefix
```

where region_code is the integer column in the table and the region_prefix variable holds an integer value

The `region_code` is the integer column in the table containing values like `1199, 1200, 1300, 1499` while the region_prefix variable (from the program) holds integer values like `11, 12, 13, 14`.

What I now want to achive with this filter option is to perform an integer division on `region_code` (hence cut everything behind the decimal place) to be able to compare it with `region_prefix`.

**Example:**

```
region_prefix = 11
```

Assume that in the Region table exists a entry with

```
region_code = 1199
```

The calculation within the filter should look like this

```
1199 / 100 = 11
```

So with this result I am able to filter for `region_prefix (11=11)`.
**This works just fine with MSSQL (Microsoft).**

Unfortunately (in my case) **MySQL** division operator `/` does not do integer divisions. So the result of `1199/100` will be `11.99` and so my query will not find a fitting entry in the DB (because 11.99 != 11).
Nevertheless MySQL actually has the inter division implemented: the **DIV** operator.

So the following SQL query works just fine for me:

```
SELECT * FROM Region where region_code DIV 100 = 11;
```

**So my question is:**
*How do I get the SQLAlchemy `filter` method to use `DIV` instead of `/` operator? Is this possible? Or is the only workaround to use native queries?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily SQLAlchemy allows for custom operators. There are simple ways of doing this (simply specifying in the query) or more complex versions of doing it (fully defining the new operator and making it multi database aware). So it depends on what you're looking for.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html?highlight=operators#redefining-and-creating-new-operators

```
region = (session
    .query(Region)
    .filter(Region.region_code.op('div')(region_prefix))
    .one()
)
```

And the fancy way:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#types-operators

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer

class DivisibleInteger(Integer):
    class comparator_factory(Integer.Comparator):
        def div(self, other):
            return self.op('div')(other)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Exactly what I was looking for. Now I'm going to find out if I get it to run on MySQL and MSSQL.

Comment: @cyphorious: I'm not exactly sure how to do that straight away with an operator, but here's a nice example with custom types: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/compiler.html#greatest-function

Comment: I still do not know how to do that too, what is 'div' ? how to implement it as my custom operator? I can't use it directly in my python project. and I can not find any useful info in docs.

Comment: @Versus: the documentation links have been changed unofrtunately, but this should help you: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html?highlight=operators#redefining-and-creating-new-operators

Answer (score 0):

Why not perform the division operation separately in your python script, saving the result to a variable, then pass the variable in your query instead of the operation?

Comment: Of course I could do that (altought I had to preload data from the DB). But this is not an answer to my question if there is some SQLAlchemy magic I'm not aware of. I already have a different algorithm to have a working application, but the aim of this question is to learn more about SQLAlchemy.